# Should a search page have a clear button?

Tags: web-applications

Its probably a very subjective question, but here it goes....We're building a website that will provide basic and advanced search criteria. The advanced search criteria will be upto 50 fields, checkboxes, textboxes, etc.

I had a look at some popular websites, and a few of them like http://www.google.com/advanced_product_search do not have a clear button. I can't decide if there should be a clear button and the case for or against it.

I do understand that we have a lot of fields and the users could potentially want to clear all the fields that they entered. I know that these requirements should come from the client, but they can't decide if they want one or not.

So what would be the case for or against it? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think this question might be better off in ui.stackexchange.com

Comment: Your company's app? http://i.imgur.com/QK8HI.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I don't like reset buttons. I have a few times filled out a lot of information and then by mistake hit the wrong button because it was placed where my mind told me the submit button would be.

Instead you could make it so the field contents are highlighted when onblur. This makes it easy to type new stuff or delete what was already there.